# Create a cell array of cell arrays

Tags: matlab, csv, cell-array

I have some .csv files in a directory and I would like to create a cell array in which every cell is a cell array containing the data of one .csv file.

For example, one of my .csv files named `example.csv` could be like this:

```
126; 1; d; 0.0238343
10; 1; d; 8.05893e-08
48; 1; d; 0.000204261
8; 1; d; 3.02726e-08
20; 1; d; 2.17914e-07
41; 1; d; 0.000179662
75; 1; d; 0.00204058
0; 1; d; 2.98228e-17
81; 1; d; 0.00241941
17; 1; d; 4.04806e-06
128; 1; d; 0.0141687
```

The first two columns always contain integers (the second one can have only 1 or 0), the third contains always a single character (it can be either `d` or `p`) and the fourth contains only floating point numbers.

Right now this is what I do for a single file:

```
file = fopen('example.csv');
csv_file = textscan(file, '%s%s%s%s', 'delimiter', ';', 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(file);
csv_file = csv_file{1};
csv_file(:,1) = num2cell( str2double(csv_file(:,1)) );
csv_file(:,2) = num2cell( str2double(csv_file(:,2)) );
csv_file(:,4) = num2cell( str2double(csv_file(:,4)) );
```

at the end the variable `csv_file` contains a cell array like this:

```
[126]    [1]    'd'    [    0.0238]
[ 10]    [1]    'd'    [8.0589e-08]
[ 48]    [1]    'd'    [2.0426e-04]
[  8]    [1]    'd'    [3.0273e-08]
[ 20]    [1]    'd'    [2.1791e-07]
[ 41]    [1]    'd'    [1.7966e-04]
[ 75]    [1]    'd'    [    0.0020]
[  0]    [1]    'd'    [2.9823e-17]
[ 81]    [1]    'd'    [    0.0024]
[ 17]    [1]    'd'    [4.0481e-06]
[128]    [1]    'd'    [    0.0142]
```

How can i do this for every .csv file in my directory in such a way that in the end I end up with a single variable containing all the cell arrays?

I need this so then I can work on all the cell arrays as I want, without the need to extract them into a variable all the time.

Comment: Use [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to output a list of files and loop through them.

Comment: I did that, but `csv_file` will be overwritten every time

Comment: @SardarUsama I'm sorry I don't understand. Could you make an example?

Comment: put this in your loop (assuming loop counter "i"):   all_files{i} = csv_file;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what suggested to you in the comments:

```
filename=dir;             %attributes
filename={filename.name}; %Extracting filenames
len=length(filename);     %Number of files
files = cell(1,len );     %Pre-allocation
for m=1:len
    file = fopen(filename{k});
    csv_file = textscan(file, '%s%s%s%s', 'delimiter', ';', 'CollectOutput', true);
    fclose(file);

    %Your array manipulations
    csv_file = csv_file{1};
    csv_file(:,1) = num2cell( str2double(csv_file(:,1)) );
    csv_file(:,2) = num2cell( str2double(csv_file(:,2)) );
    csv_file(:,4) = num2cell( str2double(csv_file(:,4)) );

    files{m}= csv_file;   %Saving result of each iteration in an index of a cell array  
end
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much!